# Dead Tap/Pipes?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrases, word-in-context

I know that the word 'dead' can be used to describe a dead phone line or dead power outlet, but can it be used to describe a non functioning tap or water pipes connected to it, if no water is passing through them?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard that use, so I'd avoid it.

An expression for a water pipe would be "the pipe has gone dry" or similar.

You can also say "The pipe is blocked".  Usually when a tap is not functioning it is "leaking" or "dripping" (which is the opposite problem).  If there is water in the pipe, but nothing coming out of the tap then just say "The tap isn't working; it won't turn on."